# Tomcat restart, not all apps start

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat5.5

I've an interesting problem about start/restart of tomcat 5.5 I've deployed a number of webapps on Tomcat. All webapps work correctly. Every time  I restart tomcat, not all applications will restart. If I click  the tomcat manager start link manually then that webapp will start.

Can anyone suggest a solution or idea to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are you starting Tomcat from command line or from IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs directory, look at your catalina.out log. This will provide you with some more information. You might be running out of either heap or permgen space.

Typically when my apps won't start it is due to some configuration error (bad file system path that the app is depending on ) or some memory issue. The log should give you some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a timeout? As said by zmf, logs will tell.